# JavaScript step-progress bar only transitioning correctly on first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const stepOne = document.querySelector(".step-1");
const stepTwo = document.querySelector(".step-2");
const stepThree = document.querySelector(".step-3");
const stepFour = document.querySelector(".step-4");
const stepFive = document.querySelector(".step-5");
const steps = document.querySelectorAll(".step");
const texts = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-text");
let active = 1;
let previous;

const updateProgress = () => {
    texts.forEach((text, i) => {
        text.classList.remove("leave-left", "leave-right", "enter-left", "enter-right");
    });
    // Toggle active attr on each step
    steps.forEach((step, i) => {
        if (i < active) {
            step.classList.add("active");
        } else {
            step.classList.remove("active");
        }
    });
    // Transition the descriptions
    texts.forEach((text, i) => {
        if ((i + 1) < active || (i + 1) < active) {
            text.classList.remove("active");
        } else if ((i + 1) > active) {
            text.classList.remove("active");
        } else {
            text.classList.add("active");
        }
        if ((i + 1) === previous && previous > active) {
            text.classList.add("leave-right");
            texts[active - 1].classList.add("enter-left");
        } else if ((i + 1) === previous && previous < active) {
            text.classList.add("leave-left");
            texts[active - 1].classList.add("enter-right");
        }
    });
};


stepOne.addEventListener("click", () => {
    previous = active;
    active = 1;
    updateProgress();
});

stepTwo.addEventListener("click", () => {
    previous = active;
    active = 2
    updateProgress();
});

stepThree.addEventListener("click", () => {
    previous = active;
    active = 3
    updateProgress();
});

stepFour.addEventListener("click", () => {
    previous = active;
    active = 4
    updateProgress();
});

stepFive.addEventListener("click", () => {
    previous = active;
    active = 5
    updateProgress();
});
```

```css
.progress-bar-container {
    padding: 2em 0;
}

#progress-bar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0c435a;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/** Status dots **/
#progress-bar li:before {
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    content: '';
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #0c435a;
    background-color: #0c435a;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all .8s;
}

#progress-bar li:hover::before {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .3s;
    border: 2px solid #b78e15;
    background-color: #b78e15;
}

/** Highlights active status dot **/
#progress-bar li.active:before {
    border-color: #b78e15;
    background-color: #b78e15;
    transition: all;
}

/** Horizontal line **/
#progress-bar li:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0c435a;
    top: 10px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all;
}

/** Removes line before first status dot **/
#progress-bar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

/** Highlights line up to active status dot **/
#progress-bar li.active:after {
    background-color: #b78e15;
    transition: all;
}

/** Display the relevant description**/
.progress-text-wrapper h4 {
    color: #0c435a;
    padding-bottom: 0.7em;
}

.progress-text-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1em auto;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.4s;
    transition: height 0.4s;
}

.progress-text {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    padding: 0 5%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.progress-text.active {
    /* visible event content */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.progress-text.enter-right {
    -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
    -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
    animation-name: cd-enter-right;
}

.progress-text.enter-left {
    -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
    -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
    animation-name: cd-enter-left;
}


.progress-text.leave-right {
    -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
    -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
    animation-name: cd-enter-right;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

.progress-text.leave-left {
    -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
    -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
    animation-name: cd-enter-left;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}


@-webkit-keyframes cd-enter-right {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-enter-right {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes cd-enter-right {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-enter-left {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-enter-left {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes cd-enter-left {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
        -o-transform: translateX(0%);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
            <h2 class="">Process</h2>
            <p class="py-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
                et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <div class="progress-bar-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <ul id="progress-bar">
                            <li class="step-1 step active">One</li>
                            <li class="step-2 step">Two</li>
                            <li class="step-3 step">Three</li>
                            <li class="step-4 step">Four</li>
                            <li class="step-5 step">Five</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="progress-text-wrapper">
            <ol>
                <li class="progress-text active">
                    <h4>One</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-text">
                    <h4>Two</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-text">
                    <h4>Three</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-text">
                    <h4>Four</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li class="progress-text">
                    <h4>Five</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

I have the following progress bar, which has a horizontal line and a description below for each step. [image]

The line works correctly, and the description itself changes correctly. However I want the descriptions to 'slide' left or right 'out of' the window as the user selects a different status. The transitioning works correctly, but only the first time a status is clicked. After that, although the description still changes correctly, there is no transition; just an instant change.

What is odd is that if I call manually

```
texts.forEach((text, i) => {
    text.classList.remove("leave-left", "leave-right", "enter-left", "enter-right");
});
```

after every click, then it works correctly.

Also open to overall better solutions.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a runnable snippet ?

Comment: Something is missing from the provided code... Probably some library to render the steps bar. Please edit.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, quite new to this. I've added the snippet. If you click through the steps the first time, all works well. But then try going back and clicking and you'll notice the transitions stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with `@keyframes` animations is they are triggered on class addition.
If the element already has the class... Well, there is no change right?

Then... There is a timing issue.
When removing the animation classes... if you re-add one right away because of a matching condition. It is like it was never removed. A 1ms `setTimeout` is usefull in that case. So the class removal had time to be redrawn before it is re-added.

Now, removing the animation clas is not all. You have to make sure to add/remove the `active` class too. It has to be at the same moment you add/remove the animation class.

Also... I improved the way to add the eventListeners and renamed variables with meaningful names, which also removed all the `+1` or `-1` calculations on the index. Indexes are zero-based.... Use the zero-base. ;)

```js
const steps = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".step"));
const texts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".progress-text"));
let currentlyActive = 0;
let nowInactive;

const updateProgress = () => {

  // Case where user click on the currently active step...
  if (currentlyActive === nowInactive) {
    return
  }

  // Toggle active attr on each step
  steps.forEach((step, index) => {
    step.classList.toggle("active", index <= currentlyActive);
  });

  // Transition the descriptions
  texts.forEach((text, index) => {

    // Remove all animation classes
    text.classList.remove("leave-left", "leave-right", "enter-left", "enter-right");

    // Animation direction for both element to be animated
    if (currentlyActive < nowInactive) {
      animateTexts(nowInactive, "leave-right", currentlyActive, "enter-left");
    }
    if (currentlyActive > nowInactive) {
      animateTexts(nowInactive, "leave-left", currentlyActive, "enter-right");
    }
  });

}

const animateTexts = (
  nowInactive,
  nowInactiveDir,
  currentlyActive,
  currentlyActiveDir
) => {

  // nowInactive stars leaving
  // That needs a tiny delay to make sure any animation class removal has been redrawn
  setTimeout(() => {
    texts[nowInactive].classList.add(nowInactiveDir);
  }, 1)
  
  // After the leave animation is done
  setTimeout(() => {
  
    // Remove the classes on the nowInactive
    texts[nowInactive].classList.remove("active", nowInactiveDir);

    // currentlyActive enters
    texts[currentlyActive].classList.add("active", currentlyActiveDir)
  }, 400)
}

// Click event listeners
steps.forEach((step, index) => {
  step.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
    // Zero-based indexes are setted here
    nowInactive = currentlyActive
    currentlyActive = index;

    updateProgress();
  });
});
```

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  padding: 2em 0;
}

#progress-bar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0c435a;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/** Status dots **/

#progress-bar li:before {
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  content: '';
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #0c435a;
  background-color: #0c435a;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .8s;
}

#progress-bar li:hover::before {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
  border: 2px solid #b78e15;
  background-color: #b78e15;
}


/** Highlights active status dot **/

#progress-bar li.active:before {
  border-color: #b78e15;
  background-color: #b78e15;
  transition: all;
}


/** Horizontal line **/

#progress-bar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0c435a;
  top: 10px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all;
}


/** Removes line before first status dot **/

#progress-bar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}


/** Highlights line up to active status dot **/

#progress-bar li.active:after {
  background-color: #b78e15;
  transition: all;
}


/** Display the relevant description**/

.progress-text-wrapper h4 {
  color: #0c435a;
  padding-bottom: 0.7em;
}

.progress-text-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s;
}

.progress-text {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  padding: 0 5%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.progress-text.active {
  /* visible event content */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.progress-text.enter-right {
  -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
  -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
  animation-name: cd-enter-right;
}

.progress-text.enter-left {
  -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
  -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
  animation-name: cd-enter-left;
}

.progress-text.leave-right {
  -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
  -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-right;
  animation-name: cd-enter-right;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.progress-text.leave-left {
  -webkit-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
  -moz-animation-name: cd-enter-left;
  animation-name: cd-enter-left;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  -moz-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-enter-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-enter-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes cd-enter-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-enter-left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-enter-left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes cd-enter-left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <h2 class="">Process</h2>
  <p class="py-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </p>
  <div class="progress-bar-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <ul id="progress-bar">
          <li class="step active">One</li>
          <li class="step">Two</li>
          <li class="step">Three</li>
          <li class="step">Four</li>
          <li class="step">Five</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="progress-text-wrapper">
  <ol>
    <li class="progress-text active">
      <h4>One</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="progress-text">
      <h4>Two</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="progress-text">
      <h4>Three</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="progress-text">
      <h4>Four</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="progress-text">
      <h4>Five</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: The trick about @keyframes animations triggering on class addition is new to me. Thanks for bringing to my attention. All working now.

Comment: Just to be clear... If the class is already there and you add it again... There is no change. Doing `element.classList.add("test").classList.remove("test").classList.add("test").classList.remove("test").classList.add("test").classList.remove("test")` **does nothing**. It does not toggle a `test` class three times quickly. ;)